# Hibernate in java

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

this is my console application that I make it with JDBC . now i want convert it to Hibernate codes . i make a class for session that every time i want i call it instead of repreat codes.here is my code :

```
public class Repository {
private static SessionFactory factory;

public static Session OpenSession(String newsession) throws SQLException {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return  session;
}
}
```

I try to use it for get student in my code . but it doesn't work. any body can help me :

```
public  class ManageStudent extends Repository  {

static String yourstcode;

public static Student getStudent() throws SQLException {
    yourstcode = Console.getInputString("enter your code");
    String getStudent = "FROM Student SE WHERE SE.studentcode=" + yourstcode;
    Session resultSet = OpenSession(getStudent);
    Student student = new Student();
    while (resultSet.equals(resultSet)) {
        student.setStudentcode(resultSet.toString("studentcode"));
    }
    return student;
}
}
```

Comment: `session.close();`. You close your `Session` immediatley after you open it...

Comment: ..and you do nothing with the sql (`String getStudent`/ `newsession` = dead code)

Comment: can you help me to correct it